# Electronic simulation packages

Tags: simulation

Any opinions on the best intuitive drag and drop electronic simulator package to buy for uni students doing project work?

Comment: Why specifically do you want to buy? Why you can not accept open source or free software? Your uni should have also tools available for you as a student for classwork.

Answer (score 1):

We had been using whatever Spice variety came in the OrCad package, but have switched to LTSpice, which does pretty much the same thing, is free, and will run in any OS.  It's saved us money, is more convenient in that our students can all run their own copy, legally, and our Circuits instructor has barely noticed the difference